# Avformat cannot seek to beginning of file

Tags: libavcodec, libav, libavformat

I need to quickly seek thru `H.264` encoded video stream in `MP4` container. I am using libav to decode frames, so I stumbled upon `avformat_seek_file()` method.

My problem is, assuming `H.264` stream begins with keyframe, when I seek to timestamp 0 (regardless of time_base), I should be at the beggining of the stream. But Im not. I usually get few seconds into video. Also, if I seek to, for example 10 seconds, I usually get around 12 or so. Is it possible for keyframes to be so "rare"? It seems that `AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY` has no impact on seek result. Tested on multiple `FullHD H.264 MP4` videos.

Code:

```
unsigned long seekTo = 0;
//Doesen´t actually matter for 0 since it will be also 0
seekTo = av_rescale_q(seekTo, AVRational{1, AV_TIME_BASE}, pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->time_base);
int result = avformat_seek_file(pFormatCtx, videoStream, INT_FAST64_MIN, seekTo, seekTo, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY);
avcodec_flush_buffers(pCodecCtx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [av_seek_frame](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#gaa23f7619d8d4ea0857065d9979c75ac8) instead. Read [here](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2011-September/000624.html) for some gotchas about using that and seeking around.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is, assuming H.264 stream begins with keyframe, when I seek to timestamp 0 (regardless of time_base), I should be at the beggining of the stream

Note that some files can have their first keyframe at a negative DTS, e.g. you need to seek to timestamp -1 or something like this.

You can set the flag inside AVFMT_SEEK_TO_PTS into `AVInputFormat::flags` before opening the `AVFormatContext` to use PTS which will be 0-based.